# Some files in Mail.app not attaching, while others do

Tags: finder, mail.app, permission

I'm experiencing some issues when attaching *some* files when composing a new email in Mail.app resulting in missing image previews or in some instances, files not attaching at all.

In the case of png, jpg and "images", the image preview, filename, etc. is missing altogether. When I option-click these file and select "Save to downloads" the file doesn't download or appear in my "downloads" folder.

[image]

When I attach other media based files, mov, psd, mov – these files show up as "downloading" while PDF's, zip, svg will attach just fine. As a note, I am not trying to send zips or large files through email, this is merely a test.
[image]

This problem was previously fixed by deleting .plists and essentially nuking Library files related to Mail.app but has decided to return. I cannot determine why it returned as I haven't installed new apps or made changes to mail.app, library files, etc.

I've fixed permissions via disk dtility by booting into the utility as well as fixing permissions via finder, both don't fix this issue.

If all else fails, I might have to clean install Ventura. Any help is appreciated.